# How do I make a HTML GET form with an action url that does not include ?<id>= in it?

Tags: java, html

I use the Java spark web framework and using it for REST API's.

The GET structure is `/foo/bar` not `/foo?name=bar`. However with using HTML the form always submits like the later example and so Java Spark can not understand it.

Java Spark GET method Example:

```
 get("/hello/:name", (request, response) -> {
                    return "Hello: " + request.params(":name");
            });
```

HTML GET form :

```
<form method="GET" action="/hello">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple javascript function, you can build the action url.

```
<script>
function submitFunction() {
   document.form1.action= "/hello/" + document.form1.name.value;
   // alert(document.form1.action);
   document.form1.submit();
   }
</script>

<form method="GET" name="form1">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="submitFunction()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! works perfect. I am curious to know if there is another method however, that does not require javascript.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible with only HTML tags, you need some scripting to do that.